# Setting a default selected value in DropDownList in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, html-select

In MVC3 I have this code at my controller. It retrieves a List of IDs\Names from Installation table and creates a ViewBag

```
var vs = dba.Installation.OrderBy(q => q.InstName).ToList();
ViewBag.Vessels = new SelectList(vs, "InstId", "InstName");
```

Now, at my view. I want to render the list in a dropdown list. I used the Html helper that works fine...

```
@Html.DropDownList("InstId",(SelectList)ViewBag.Vessels, "- Select one -")
```

I need to set first item in the ViewBag List as a default selected value, instead of "- Select one -" text.

How can I do it?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's an overload for the `SelectList` constructor that takes 4 arguments.  The last of which is the default selected object.  E.g:

```
ViewBag.Vessels = new SelectList(vs, "InstId", "InstName", selectedValue);
```

Where `selectedValue` is an object of whatever type is in your list.

Comment: Thanks @WheretheresaWill. OMG! I did't realize that overload. Stupid me.

Answer (score 4):

> I need to set first item in the ViewBag List as a default selected
>   value, instead of "- Select one -" text.

Then you need to select the first item in your list (`vs`) and get it's id and use it as the `selecedValue` in the SelectList:

```
ViewBag.Vessels = new SelectList(vs, "InstId", "InstName", 
    vs.FirstOrDefault().InstId);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also create an Helper class for Dropdownlist
It will have a method to set the text as by default text for every dropdownlist in you solution

Comment: Thanks @K2_Ketu but as WheretheresaWill said, there is a overload which includes this option.