# MVC4 - Setting Initially Selected Item in DropDownList

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, drop-down-menu

I am passing in a list of objects to my View via a model

```
@model MyModel.ObjectViewModel
```

I am new to MVC and am trying to set the initially selected item of a `dropdownlist` in my view (**modelled after an Edit**).

I am then binding this to a drop down list as follows

```
<label for="ddlObjects">Select Object</label>
@Html.DropDownList("ddlObjects", Model.AllObjectsSelectList, Model.Object.ObjectName)
```

The above does make the drop down list have the correct object selected initially, but I discovered it is only in the form of text.  The real object isn't chosen and as such the value isn't used.  How can I have a list of items, say, `"Object1"` `"Object2"`, etc and have the default be a specific one?

When I'm passing through the item I only know the text value (the name that appears in the drop down list) of the item, I don't know it's inner value so I can't really use `SelectListItem {Text = "X", Value= "Y"}`

I have searched here and through google, and there are options for setting the intially selected value, however they are using methods like `@Html.DropDownList` for which doesn't seem to let me specify a control name, and in my controller I specifically reference the name of the control.

Comment: http://forums.asp.net/t/1761365.aspx/1      **OR** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298346/setting-a-default-selected-value-in-dropdownlist-in-mvc3

Comment: That kind of works in that it says it should set the default to X but it doesn't seem to change it when I actually run the app and go to the page.  (second link).

Comment: Why not use **Viewbag** or **ViewData** to carry your selected id(value) to view and assign that value to selected value overload for dropdown , So your selected id(value) could be dynamic.

Comment: Because I don't have the ID, I only have the text value.  I'm dealing with data I get from SQL and instead of storing the ID and using Joins to normalise the table it is just passing the string name of the object.

Comment: A bit curious , Are you sure you are passing valueFields to your dropdown or just **Textfields** Why not use **@HTML.DropdownFor()** method ??

Comment: Try to pass your TextField and Valuefield both as the name Something like this  **SelectListItem {Text = "X", Value= "X"}** .

Comment: I'm rather new and as far as I know the DropdownFor doesn't let me specifiy a name for the control, and I need the name to use within my controller.  I will tr passing the Text and Value as the same, but as an object could actually be Text="MyObject" Value="3" I don't know if that will work.

Comment: I've managed to do it now, it's not a pretty solution by any means, but it works.  Kind of similar to your suggestions @suraj singh as I managed to convince the SQL devs to return the ID needed, but I sitll have to do some tinkering.

I will post up the answer tomorrow if anybody else needs a similar quick fix.

Comment: Glad my suggestions helped ,yes please post answer it will definitely help me and other people too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My work around wasn't pretty, but it could be easily refactored to be much nicer.  It will just be a case of some effort which at present I don't have time for - but I will in the next week or so.

I created a method in my controller which I pass in my list of items (selectList, which you would think would work anyway... but it doesn't) then I work out which is the object I require and set the Selected property to true.

```
private List<SelectListItem> GetListOfObjectTypes(SelectList selectList, string objectTypeName, string objectTypeId)
{
    List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
    foreach (METAObjectType item in selectList.Items)
    {
         bool isSelected = false;
         if (item.Name == objectTypeName)
         {
                isSelected = true;
         }
         items.Add(new SelectListItem {Selected= isSelected, Text=item.Name, Value=item.ObjectTypeId.ToString()});
        }
        return items;
    }
```

I then just pass this through to my View and set it as the list in the @Html.DropDownList and it will now select the correct item by default.