# Adding default value DropDownList

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor, html-helper

From my controller I am sending the following List to my View.

```
    ViewBag.PROF= new SelectList(db.PROF.Where(y => y.USER_ID == user), "PROF_ID", "PROF_NAME");
```

When I display the above list in my View it gets displayed perfectly.

```
@Html.DropDownList("PROF", null, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

However, in the list that is been displayed I want to show the 3rd item as the default Item (or the item that will be displayed by default). How can I make this work ?

Comment: SelectList has a SelectedItem property, try setting that (after you create the list).

Comment: You mean from the VIew ? or controller ? @AlexPaven

Comment: Controller, right after you create the SelectList.

Comment: I don't see a 'SelectedItem' on the list. Can you help me out please.

Comment: Should've been 'SelectedValue'. Added an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe a Selected value can be added to `@Html.DropDownList`. Simple mark the value you want as the default to be Selected = true and it'll be defaulted to that.

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectedValue.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.selectlist.aspx

Note you can pass the selected value in the constructor of the SelectList as a fourth parameter. You can only use the alternative written in another answer here if the items are SelectListItems, as far as I know. Also note this question has been asked many times before on stack overflow, even if not all answers seem to be quite right there are plenty that can give you hints. For instance the first item in the Related list: [Setting a default selected value in DropDownList in MVC3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16298346/setting-a-default-selected-value-in-dropdownlist-in-mvc3?rq=1)